# Display Json data jQuery PHP MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I cant find answer to my problem...the truth is im new to jQuery and JSON.

On login page i want to display top customers and top tracks, when page loads.
Iv displyed them via echo from php, but i want to create JSON object and send it to login ...loop there and display it in unordered list.

Can you guys help me with creating JSON and displaying it in jquery.

Here's my code:

jQuery:

```
/*  Function to load top Customers  */
    function loadCustomers() {

        /* Create data string to call functions in php*/
        var dataString ="function1=loadCustomers&function2=loadTracks";

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: "login.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(data) {
                $("#error").show();
                $("#errormsg").html(data.FirstName);

                //how can i display Json data in unordered list ? #customerList

            },

            error: function() {
                $("#error").show();
                $("#errormsg").text("cant display data");
            }

        });
    }
```

PHP :

```
 }else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {

    //JSON customers array
    $customers = array();


    if ($_GET["function1"] == "loadCustomers") {
        try {

            $customerStmt = $conn->prepare("Select customer.FirstName, customer.LastName, customer.City, sum(invoice.Total) from invoice INNER JOIN customer on invoice.CustomerId = customer.CustomerId group by invoice.CustomerId order by sum(invoice.total) DESC LIMIT 5");
            $customerStmt->execute();

            $customerRows = $customerStmt->fetchAll();

            //how to create JSON data to send it

           header("Content-type: application/json");
           echo json_encode($customerRows);

        }catch (PDOException $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, from the code it looks like you are responding with multiple customers, but in jQuery you are accessing the data directly without accessing the array. So it should look like this

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "login.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
        });

        $( "<ul/>", {
            "class": "my-new-list",
            html: items.join( "" )
        }).appendTo( "#customerList" );
    },

    error: function() {
        $("#error").show();
        $("#errormsg").text("cant display data");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i couldn't recive JSON data from PHP.
After hours of googling and trying diffrent solutions i finally found an error..

When you read from database you have to set it to utf-8 charset.

I was fixing this problem in code with utf8_encode function...
You have to set it in new definition of PDO object :

```
 $conn= new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;charset=utf8", $user, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

After this change im sending JSON data .